# How can I differentiate between a broken iPad power button and some sort of software problem?

Tags: ipad, power

Pressing the power button on my iPad mini 4 doesn't turn the screen on and off... but a long press on the button will still bring up the "slide to power off" prompt (and if I power off the iPad, pressing the power button will turn it back on ).

If nothing worked at all I would figure it's a hardware problem and look into getting it repaired, but the fact the the "power off" feature works even though the power button doesn't seem to sleep/wake the screen has me puzzled.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

#### There is an issue with the display lock sensor and/or flex cable.

I do remember seeing this on several occasions and this is a hardware issue with the sensor or flex cable from that sensor.  When you have a smart cover, it's that sensor in conjunction with a magnet that turns off the display (sleeps the iPad). What's happening is the sensor is faulty and "tricking" the iPad into thinking it's still open and it doesn't turn off.

You'll have to take it in for service.

#### Workaround:  Change the Display Lock

Go to *Settings → Display & Brightness* then check to see if the *Lock/Unlock* is enabled.  If so, turn it off.  Obviously, if you have a smart cover it won't work any more.

If you're not using a smart cover, then the issue is technically moot - you can use the button to put it to sleep or wait until the autosleep (timer) put's it to sleep for you.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way it works on my iPad Pro.  Pressing the Power button turns the iPad display off and on. Holding it down for a few seconds brings up the shutdown slider. If you can't turn the display off and on what do you do when screen turns off? Press the Home button? Really only thing you're missing, it sounds, is your ability to turn the screen off when you desire. Or did I miss something? You can turn the screen on with the Home button.

It sounds as if something may be wrong with your button.

Comment: To be sure we're talking about the same thing: I'm talking about the power button on the top of the ipad, not the home button at the bottom.

Comment: yes, my bad. I rewrote my answer.  thanks.